# Remove character in all strings in a string array

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework library.

If I have this array `string[] elements`. And I want to remove this character `\"` in all of them, how can I do it in one instruction?

I know that I can do this:

```
foreach(string element in elements)
   element = element.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Is there a way to do it in one sentence? (without using foreach).

Comment: If you are allowed to change the `elements` reference, then you can do it using LINQ. Otherwise you could create a `ForEach` extension method which operates on arrays.

Comment: But `"\""` is the same as `"` not `\"` since it is an escapse sequence.

Comment: You cannot do _anything_ with `n`-elements without looping them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You miss the point.  OP didn't say "without looping"...the statement is "without using foreach".  A subtle difference.  I think the point is the part about "in one sentence".

Comment: Your `foreach` does not even compile, you have to use a `for`-loop.

Comment: Why do you down vote this question? I think it is not necessary. You can explain what is wrong and show me the right way to do it. And even, none has told me why they are down voting.

Comment: @VansFannel: you state that the `foreach` works but that you want "one sentence". So this question was off-topic if it actually _would_ work because you're asking to "improve" working code(you can ask such questions on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)). The other reason why this is a poor question is that it actually doesn't work, it does not even compile without a `for`-loop. Finally the "one sentence" apporach is less efficient since it needs to create a complete new collection instead of just changing it's content.

Comment: But I think this question can help people to avoid this error. If they see a question with negative points, I think, they won't read it. Thanks, Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new array with new values:

```
var newValues = elements.Select(x => x.Replace("\"", string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

If creating a new array would be a problem you should stick with loop approach.

In addition you can't change a `foreach` loop variable like that.You should get a compiler error:

> Cannot assign to 'element' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

You will need a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    elements[i] = elements[i].Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Which is also a (less efficient) loop.

Comment: Completely right, but you don't see it. LinQ is often sugar coating... :D

Comment: @Abbas: but in this case it's poisoned sugar.

Comment: no it is not if array is not too big.why are you making this such a big deal? who is saying linq removes loop and magically changes the valus?

Comment: @Selman22: I agree with you. This is what OP asked for and that is what he gets.

Comment: @Selman22: because it's suggesting the wrong things. It's less efficient and it's not even more readable. So there's no benefit.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code won't work since it just creates new instances of `string`. You won't update your array with the new values.

You could use LINQ's [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) to get what you want:

```
elements = elements.Select(x => x.Replace("\"", string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

This code will create a new array with the modified values from `elements`. Note that this code is less efficient that a regular `for` loop, which I would recommend in this case.

Comment: Is also a loop and even less efficient than OP's code.

Comment: True, noted the performance impact in my answer. You did notice that OP asked for a one-liner, not the most efficient code?

Answer (score 1):

In one line, sure, easy, just remove that newline and indent:

```
foreach(string element in elements) element = element.Replace(@"\"", string.Empty);
```

Without using a foreach loop? Sure, use for instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++) elements[i] = elements[i].Replace(@"\"", string.Empty);
```

You might've noticed the `@` I put in there. Very important, basically ignores escape sequences, so it actually gets rid of `\"` instead of just `"`

Comment: The `foreach` doesn't compile.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Nope, and it won't. Not ever. The for does though. And I'm sure the asker knows the foreach won't compile, which is why he asked for a way to do it without foreach

Comment: The `@` is not necessary because Vans only wants to remove the backslash, and the `@` symbol is of no help in that case. ;)

Anyway, removing the new line character is like *cheating* and probably not what the asker needs. :P

Comment: _"I'm sure the asker knows the foreach won't compile, which is why he asked for a way to do it without foreach"_ OP says: _"I know that I can do this:  ... foreach"_. You still don't mention the fact that your first approach does not work. Otherwise i would have removed the downvote.